Video feed in React app using objectFit: contain introduces white spaces, but cover zooms in too much
I’m working on a React app that includes a live video feed from the user’s webcam. The video feed is displayed using HTML  and processed by the MediaPipe pose model, alongside a Three.js scene for rendering 3D objects.
Problem:

When using objectFit: 'cover', the video fills the container, but it is too zoomed in.
When using objectFit: 'contain', the video displays correctly, but introduces white spaces above and below on mobile (or on the sides in landscape mode).

I want the video to display naturally without zooming too much and without introducing white spaces. I’ve tried different combinations of width, height, objectFit, and CSS transforms, but haven’t found a solution that works well on both desktop and mobile.
Code:
Here’s the relevant part of my React component:
<video
  ref={videoRef}
  style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    width: '100%', 
    height: '100%',  
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%) scaleX(-1)', 
    objectFit: 'cover', 
  }}
  autoPlay
  playsInline
  muted
/>

What I’ve tried:

Using objectFit: 'cover': Fills the container but results in a zoomed-in video, which cuts off parts of the video.
Using objectFit: 'contain': Shows the entire video, but results in white space at the top and bottom on mobile and on the sides in landscape.
Adjusting width, height, and transform properties doesn’t seem to resolve the issue for all screen sizes.

My Goal:
I want the video feed to:

Display naturally (without zooming in).
Not introduce white spaces on any device (both mobile and desktop).

Any advice on how to achieve this behavior would be greatly appreciated!

Try using object-fit: fill The video will stretch or squish to fit the ratio or size without hiding anything or showing white spaces.
See this example on w3schools
You can also set aspect ratio of parent div to fit in a given ratio
Hoe this helps...
